# Want to remove the stop words from the data frame using nltk

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have the data frame which contains the reviews of movies. How I can remove the stopwords from that.

This is my dataframe.There are two columns Reviews(reviews of the movies) and label(pos or neg).

```
                                Reviwes                 label  
Bromwell High is a cartoon comedy. It ran at t...   pos  
Homelessness (or Houselessness as George Carli...   pos  
Brilliant over-acting by Lesley Ann Warren. Be...   pos  
This is easily the most underrated film inn th...   pos  
This is not the typical Mel Brooks film. It wa...   pos  
This isn't the comedic Robin Williams, nor is ...   pos  
Yes its an art... to successfully make a slow ...   pos  
In this "critically acclaimed psychological th...   pos  
THE NIGHT LISTENER (2006) **1/2 Robin Williams...   pos  
You know, Robin Williams, God bless him, is co...   pos  
When I first read Armistead Maupins story I wa...   pos
```

Comment: english stop words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tokenise your reviews(sent_tokeinize for multi line reviews and then word_tokenize those sentences.) Checking for "if not in stop_words" would exclude the stop_words.

Edit: thanks alexis. changed `stopwords.words('English')`to  `set(stopwords.words('English'))`

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words=set(stopwords.words('English')) #set of English stop words
remove_stop_words = lambda r:[[word for word in word_tokenize(sente) if word not in stop_words] for sente in sent_tokenize(r)]
df.Reviews = df.Reviews.str.lower().apply(remove_stop_words)
```

Example:

```
>>> r
'When I first read Armistead Maupins story I wa...   pos  Hello. hi this i skeer.'
>>> [sente for sente in sent_tokenize(r)]
['When I first read Armistead Maupins story I wa...   pos  Hello.', 'hi this i skeer.']
>>> [[word for word in word_tokenize(sente)] for sente in sent_tokenize(r)]
[['When', 'I', 'first', 'read', 'Armistead', 'Maupins', 'story', 'I', 'wa', '...', 'pos', 'Hello', '.'], ['hi', 'this', 'i', 'skeer', '.']]
>>> [[word for word in word_tokenize(sente) if word not in stop_words] for sente in sent_tokenize(r)]
[['When', 'I', 'first', 'read', 'Armistead', 'Maupins', 'story', 'I', 'wa', '...', 'pos', 'Hello', '.'], ['hi', 'skeer', '.']]
```

Comment: Your code is still really inefficient, use `set(stopwords.words('English')`. (That was probably also the problem with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's code.)